# Having difficulty parsing website with selenium and python

Tags: selenium

**Background:**

I am trying to scrape information from a [link](https://www.realestate.com.au/buy/property-house-in-vaucluse,+nsw+2030/list-1?source=refinement) but I cannot seem to get the HTML source code to further parse it.

**Link:**

https://www.realestate.com.au/buy/property-house-in-vaucluse,+nsw+2030/list-1?source=refinement

**Code:**

```
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

    preferences = {"safebrowsing.enabled": "false"}

    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", preferences)

    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

    browser = webdriver.Chrome('link_to_chrome_driver.exee',  chrome_options=chrome_options)

    url = property_link
    print(url)
    browser.get(url)
    delay = 20 # seconds

    try:
        WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'rui-button-brand pagination__link-next')))
        time.sleep(10)
    except:
        pass

    html = browser.page_source

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    print(soup)
```

**Output:**

```
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<link href="about:blank" rel="shortcut icon"/>
</head>
<body>
<script src="/149e9513-01fa-4fb0-aad4-566afd725d1b/2d206a39-8ed7-437e-a3be-862e0f06eea3/j.js"></script>
<script src="/149e9513-01fa-4fb0-aad4-566afd725d1b/2d206a39-8ed7-437e-a3be-862e0f06eea3/f.js"></script>
<script src="/149e9513-01fa-4fb0-aad4-566afd725d1b/2d206a39-8ed7-437e-a3be-862e0f06eea3/fingerprint/script/kpf.js?url=/149e9513-01fa-4fb0-aad4-566afd725d1b/2d206a39-8ed7-437e-a3be-862e0f06eea3/fingerprint&amp;token=d33b4707-4c3a-5fbb-8de6-b6889ed26c7d"></script><div></div>
</body></html>
```

**Question:**

I don't understand what is going wrong - but when I manually load the site from the any browser - the html script is significantly different. However parsing the site with selenium/bs is far too problematic - What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the link valid? The page does not even open for me.

Comment: @sushil works fine with me `https://www.realestate.com.au/buy/property-house-in-vaucluse,+nsw+2030/list-1?source=refinement` or `https://www.realestate.com.au/buy/property-house-in-vaucluse,+nsw+2030/list-1`

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS selector is incorrect.

Try to edit the css selector as below:

```
.rui-button-brand.pagination__link-next
```

Refer to: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp